# JRuby Watir phantomjs exception Unknown error (Windows says "The operation completed successfully.", but it did not.)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, jruby, watir-webdriver, child-process

Trying to use JRuby with watir-webdriver over the phantomjs driver and get the exception below.  Works with :chrome and :firefox but fails with :phantomjs.  Tried this on a colleagues machine too and if failed.  It is possible to use webdriver/phantomjs over JRuby?

Here are the details:

```
jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392) 2014-04-15 643e292 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0-b147 [Windows 7-amd64]

watir-webdriver (0.6.9)

phantomjs -v
1.9.7

irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
ChildProcess::Error: Unknown error (Windows says "The operation completed successfully.", but it  did not.)
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-    0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:325:in `handle_for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/jruby.rb:48:in `windows_handle_for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:306:in `handle_for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:137:in `std_stream_hadle_for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:109:in `setup_io'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:32:in `start'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:68:in `launch_process'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:82:in `start'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.rb:42:in `start'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/bridge.rb:20:in `initialie'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:45:in `for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.9/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/bin/jirb:13:in `(root)'
```

Comment: Also this is on Windows 7

Comment: have you downloaded phantomjs and placed it someplace that is on the path?

Comment: actually on closer examination of the stack trace, it looks like webdriver is using the child-process gem, which is what is choking for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to trying to run the child-process gem on Jruby.  This is the first time I have personally seen a problem with that, and I've run a lot of stuff using watir-webdriver (and hence webdriver) on jruby.  But I had not tried using phantomJS for my browser.

When I try this with ruby 1.9.3  it works for me

```
C:\Rubies>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
C:\Rubies>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..f887d0e36 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto "http://google.com"
=> "http://www.google.com/"
irb(main):004:0> puts b.title
Google
=> nil
```

Using Windows 8, When I tried it with Jruby, both the current release 1.7.19  and the pre-release of 9.0.0 I got the same error you did. Ruby 1.9.3 worked properly as you see above.  I also tried 64 bit versions of Ruby 2.0 (2.0.0p598) and 2.1.5 (2.1.5p273) and it worked fine.  (although for both of those, you may need to [manually update rubygems](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) if you get a ssl error trying to install or update gems)

I really do not know if the problem is jruby, or the child-process gem, so I'm not sure where a bug should be filed to get this fixed.  in the meantime if you want to use phantomJS as your browser, I suggest moving off jruby until the cause of the fault can be tracked down and fixed.

I'm going to edit the tags for the question slightly to see if we can get attention of any experts with Jruby or the gem in question.

PS  for a windows user, since PIC is now unsupported and developent on RVM 2.0 has just started, I recommend looking at [URU](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/overview) as a means to swiftly move between ruby versions.

Comment: since this works on normal ruby, I am presuming the issue is with jruby, and filed the following issue with that project  https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2598  You can track that to see if they accept and resolve the problem